# Jailbroken iPhone 5S stuck on Recovery screen

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, jailbreak

I have a Jailbroken iPhone5s Or well I had one. I couldn't install any apps or update any apps so I reset my Phone with reset all in settings It was stuck in the Recovery Screen just stuck. I then plugged it in with iTunes and done Update and Restore but then it was just stuck in that screen. I left it in there for about 6 hours and I can't seem to fix at all. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to restore your phone to the latest iOS version being signed, currently iOS 10.2.1.

You should *never* click **Reset All Content and Settings** on a jailbroken phone, because it will throw you into an irreversible boot loop and you'll be forced to restore.

Comment: How can i Update?

Comment: I hope that you have a backup of your device, either on iTunes or on iCloud, so that you can restore from it without having to lose all of your data. If you do, then proceed with the instructions found [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204184).

Comment: I Don't. Is there any other way?

Comment: Yes, there is, but if you restore with iTunes without a backup, you will lose all of your data. [Here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201252) is an article on how to do that. I'll repeat it again, though: you will lose **all** your data if you take this route. If you want to try to salvage what's left, then you could try asking another question and hopefully someone more qualified to answer that concern can help you. But if you are okay with losing *all* your data and starting from scratch as you don't have a backup, use my link. And do back your data up regularly in the future.